# Vue best practices. What should I pass as prop to a component

Tags: vue.js

For example I have simple TODO app.
Task represented by `Task` component. As storage I use `Vuex`.

For each task I store structure like

```
{
   id: 999,
   label: 'My super task',
   done: true
}
```

Questions is what I have to pass to the component as property - only `id` (and then get other data from store) or the whole data array?

Comment: is more efficient to pass the array to Task component instead of request data from each Task as it's more usage of resources to do so.
<Task v-for = "Task in Tasks"   :Element="Task" />
if your Tasks array is huge and you worry about it, make a special getter to get exact amount for pagination!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Passing whole data will make the your `Task` component independent from store.
2. Passing only `id`s of tasks will make your `Task` component dependent on store for tasks data.

Since `Task` is representing a single card, I think making it dependent on the store will increase the calls to the store since `n` number of tasks will call store for data.

It is better to get the data from store once and then enumerating the data using `v-for` directive and passing whole `task` object to your `Task` component.

Answer (score 0):

So you can pass it however you like. Keep in mind, if you're using Vuex, you don't need to pass anything as a prop since you have a central source of truth. Instead, you can call straight from the state or use a getter.

Inside your child component, you can refer to the store with `$store` in the template and `this.$store` in the script.

For example:
`const myTasks = this.$store.state.tasks` (if `tasks` is an array or collection of some sort)

`const myTask = this.$store.state.tasks[0]`

Then you have `myTask.id`, `myTask.label`, etc.

If you need a more specific example, please post more code and let me know.